# Removing li elements from ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

Is it possible using JavaScript to dynamically remove just a few li elements from a ul, given the id's of the li elements?

UPDATE about the actual issue:

I've the following list.

```html
<ul id="attributes" data-role="listview">
    <li id="attrib01">Attribute1</li>
    <li id="attrib02">Attribute2</li>
    <li id="attrib03">Attribute3</li>
    <li id="attrib04">Attribute4</li>
    <li id="attrib05">Attribute5</li>
</ul>
```

After a ajax request/response, if a particular attribute is "undefined", I want to remove it from the list.

```
if(typeof data.attrib1 === "undefined")
    $("#attrib01").remove();
```

I've made sure I'm receiving the correct ajax response. So, the problem now is, that when I remove attrib4, attrib[1-3] are being removed as well. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: I've tried $("#id-of-the-li-element").remove(). which removes all the li elements in the list.

Comment: If you put the actual id of the li as your jquery selector it would not remove all of the lis. Please include the code samples that you have tried.

Comment: So you're using jQuery? Have you looked through the documentation? Anyway, that code should only remove one element. Are you reusing IDs? Is that ID on the UL instead of the LI?

Comment: @Ashwin that actually is how you would do it with jQuery.  http://jsfiddle.net/eCbGf/ Your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: Not enough information here for this to be of any use. Run through a basic jQuery tutorial, and you'll know how to do it.

Comment: Why would you remove "attrib4" when the actual element is called "attrib04"?

Answer (score 22):

Try

```
var elem = document.getElementById('id');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you get the element then find its parent then remove the element. from the parent as follows:

```
element = document.getElementById("element-id");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

It is necessary to go through the parent so this is unavoidable.

Answer (score 3):

`$('#id').remove()` is the correct way to remove a single element. Note that element IDs must be unique in html, and that invocation must be wrapped in a DOM ready function.

[This is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wXJzc/1/) based on your html. It loops through all the list-items and removes the one whose id is not present in the data object:

```
var data = {
    attrib01: "Number 1",
    attrib02: "Number 2",
    attrib04: "Number 4"
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul > li").each(function() {
        alert(this.id in data); //check if value is defined
        if(!(this.id in data)) {
            $(this).remove();
            // This also works:
            //$('#'+this.id).remove();
        }            
    });
});​
```

It is also possible to target and remove only a single element ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wXJzc/2/)) by simply doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#attrib04").remove();
});​
```

Be careful with your IDs -- they must match exactly. `attrib04 != attrib4`

Answer (score 0):

This will make the `li` elements invisible:

```
document.getElementById("id_here").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Disclaimer: they will still be in the DOM

To remove elements from the DOM use JQuery's `.remove()` method:

```
$("#id_here").remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/