# JS: How to remove items from a list using DOM Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html, list, dom, removechild

I have to write a java script code. I have to create an array containing fruit names and insert these names as list items once the html document loads.
Once the list is loaded user would input any of the name present in the list. If user enter something else an alert will be generated. When the user enters a fruit that is in the list, that item is removed from the “fruits” list and added into a second list named "basket".

In my code i have generated the list and it is inserted in the document. And when the user enters the name it also appears in the second list. now the problem is that i can`t figure out how to remove the name from first list permanently once it is entered in the second list.

This is my Html code:

```js
// JavaScript File
var fruit = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apricot"];

function fruitList() {
    for (var i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
      // Create the list item:
      var list = document.createElement('li');
      // Set its contents:
      var node = document.createTextNode(fruit[i]);
      list.appendChild(node);
      var element = document.getElementById('fruits');
      element.appendChild(list);
    }
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function search() {
  var flag = false;
  var fruitName = document.getElementById("newfruit").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
    if (fruitName === fruit[i]) {
      // Create the list item:
      var list = document.createElement('li');
      // Set its contents:
      var node = document.createTextNode(fruitName);
      list.appendChild(node);
      var element = document.getElementById('basket');
      element.appendChild(list);
      flag = true;


      var removeFruit = document.getElementById('fruits');
      removeFruit.removeChild(removeFruit.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }

  if (flag == false) {
    alert("This fruit is not available");
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ECE 9065 - Lab 2</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: pink;
      background-color: gray;
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans‐serif;
    }
    body {
      color: purple;
      font-family: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body background="fruit.jpg">
  <h1>Fruit Shelf</h1>
  <button onclick="fruitList()">Show Fruits available in the shelf</button>
  <b><ol id="fruits"></ol></b>

  <b>Pick a fruit:</b>
  <input type="text" id="newfruit">
  <button onclick="search()">Submit</button>

  <h1>Basket</h1>
  <b><ol id="basket"></ol></b>
</body>

</html>
```

When i add a fruit for the first time from the first list, it is removed from the first list and added in the second list. But after the first time it starts randomly removing fruits from the list.
I want that if the user enters apple it is removed from the first list permanently and added in the second list basket. So if the user enters apple second time it should generate the alert that fruit is not present. And if the user enters another fruit present than it should be added in the basket list and removed from the first list. I can`t figure out how to do that. I am quite new at java script and i have just started learning it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing li elements from ul](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751111/removing-li-elements-from-ul)

Answer (score 0):

You primary issue was that **you were looping through your array and checking to see if the fruit exists in the array, but you should be checking the first list because that's the one that will change**.

See comments inline below for details:

```js
var fruit = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango" , "Apricot"];

// Get references to the two lists, because we'll need to access them more than once
var firstList = document.getElementById('fruits');
var secondList = document.getElementById('basket');

function fruitList() {
  // Loop through the array. That's ok to build the initial list
  for(var i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++)  {
    
    // Create the list item:
    var list = document.createElement('li');

    // Set its contents:
    var node = document.createTextNode(fruit [i]);
    
    // Add it to the list
    list.appendChild(node);
    
    // Append list to the document
    firstList.appendChild(list);
  }
}

function search() {
  var flag = false;   
  
  var fruitName = document.getElementById("newfruit").value;
  
  // Loop through the first list, not the array
  for (var i = 0; i < firstList.childNodes.length; i++) {
    
    // Don't search the Array for a match (you will always find your fruits there),
    // search the first list
    if (fruitName === firstList.childNodes[i].textContent) {
      
        // Create the list item:
        var list = document.createElement('li'); 
      
        // Set its contents:
        var node = document.createTextNode(fruitName);
        list.appendChild(node);  
      
        // Add to the second list
        secondList.appendChild(list);
      
        flag = true;

        // Remove from the first
        var removeFruit = document.getElementById('fruits');
        removeFruit.removeChild(removeFruit.childNodes[i]);
      
    } 
  }

  if (!flag) {
    alert("This fruit is not available");  
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  color: purple;
  font-family: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

h1 {
  color: pink;
  background-color: gray;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans‐serif;
}
```

```html
<h1 >Fruit Shelf</h1>
<button onclick="fruitList()">Show Fruits available in the shelf</button>
<b><ol id="fruits"></ol></b>

<b>Pick a fruit:</b>
<input type="text" id="newfruit">
<button onclick="search()">Submit</button>

<h1>Basket</h1>
<b><ol id="basket"></ol></b>
```

Comment: Ok now i understand my mistake. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new list item and append it to the basket list, just search for the already existing item in the fruits list and move it to the basket list like this:

```js
// JavaScript File
var fruit = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apricot"];

function fruitList() {
    for (var i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
      // Create the list item:
      var list = document.createElement('li');
      // Set its contents:
      var node = document.createTextNode(fruit[i]);
      list.appendChild(node);
      var element = document.getElementById('fruits');
      element.appendChild(list);
    }
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function search() {
  var flag = true;
  var fruit = document.getElementById("newfruit").value;

  // get all the list items from the fruits list
  var availableFruits = document.querySelectorAll("#fruits li");
  // loop through them
  for(var i = 0; i < availableFruits.length; i++) {
    var li = availableFruits[i];
    // check if the current list item have the same text as the fruit we're looking for (li.textContent.toLowerCase() == fruit.toLowerCase() if you want to ignore case sensitivity)
    if(li.textContent == fruit) { // if so
      // append it to the basket list (it will automatically be removed from the fruits list)
      document.getElementById("basket").appendChild(li);
      flag = false;
      //break; // uncomment this if you don't want to loop through the rest of the fruits (if you don't have duplicates)
    }
  }
  
  if(flag)
    alert("Fruit unavailable!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ECE 9065 - Lab 2</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: pink;
      background-color: gray;
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans‐serif;
    }
    body {
      color: purple;
      font-family: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body background="fruit.jpg">
  <h1>Fruit Shelf</h1>
  <button onclick="fruitList()">Show Fruits available in the shelf</button>
  <b><ol id="fruits"></ol></b>

  <b>Pick a fruit:</b>
  <input type="text" id="newfruit">
  <button onclick="search()">Submit</button>

  <h1>Basket</h1>
  <b><ol id="basket"></ol></b>
</body>

</html>
```

**ANOTHER WAY TO IT:**

You can acheive the same effect using the click event. The user can add fruits to basket by just clicking them. Here is how to do it:

```js
// JavaScript File
var fruit = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Apricot"];

function fruitList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
    var list = document.createElement('li');
    var node = document.createTextNode(fruit[i]);
    list.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById('fruits');
    element.appendChild(list);
    
    // HERE IS THE TRICK
    list.onclick = chooseItem;
  }
}

function chooseItem(event) {
  // get the li that was clicked
  var li = event.target;
  
  // move it to the basket list
  document.getElementById("basket").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ECE 9065 - Lab 2</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: pink;
      background-color: gray;
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans‐serif;
    }
    body {
      color: purple;
      font-family: Georgia, Cambria, "Times New Roman", serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body background="fruit.jpg">
  <h1>Fruit Shelf</h1>
  <button onclick="fruitList()">Show Fruits available in the shelf</button>
  <b><ol id="fruits"></ol></b>

  <b>No need for the textbox just click a fruit to add it!</b>
  
  <b><ol id="basket"></ol></b>
</body>

</html>
```